# What can I do to make my program work?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have been working on a project that can detect the smallest number you entered and can find its average. I had created a loop that made the code forever going until you have entered: "Quit". But for some reason, the answers the console give is always the first number you entered. Please help me find the bug and the resolution, thank you!

Here is the original code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<double> nums = new List<double>();
        bool quit = false;
        while (!quit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter as many numbers as you want, but leave a space between them, if you want to quit, please enter 'Quit'.");
            string foo = Console.ReadLine();
            if (foo == "Quit")
            {
                quit = true;
                return;
            }
            string[] tokens = foo.Split(' ');

            double oneNum;
            foreach (string s in tokens)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(s, out oneNum))
                {
                    nums.Add(oneNum);
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("You have inputed invalid number, please try again!");   
                    break;
                }

                double smallestValue = nums[0];
                double num = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count; i++)
                {
                    num = nums[i];
                    if (smallestValue > num)
                        smallestValue = num;

                }
                double mean = 0;
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count; i++)
                {
                    sum = sum + nums[i];
                }
                mean = sum / nums.Count;

                Console.WriteLine("The smallest number amoung the intergers is {0}, and their average is {1}.", smallestValue, mean);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE]. Edit your code to include the `using` statements.

Comment: `What can I do...` you could debug your code, step thru it and find the logic error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing curly brace (`}`) at the end of this loop.

```
foreach (string s in tokens)
{
    if (double.TryParse(s, out oneNum))
    {
        nums.Add(oneNum);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have inputed invalid number, please try again!");   
        break;
    }
```

Without that closing brace, all the following calculations are considered to be inside that loop! Since the code includes a call to `Console.ReadLine()`, it looks like you've finished the calculations when you've only gone through the first iteration of the loop.